# App is force closing when i run it? Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, manifest, logcat

When i run my app, and i press on a button it force closes. I fixed my Android manifest and i cannot find the problem. Here is the Logcat:

```
   03-07 23:48:53.035: D/dalvikvm(5457): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 49% free 2797K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 99ms
03-07 23:48:53.132: D/dalvikvm(5457): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 2796K/5379K, external 3471K/4335K, paused 35ms
03-07 23:48:53.691: D/dalvikvm(5457): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2798K/5379K, external 5048K/5580K, paused 53ms
03-07 23:48:54.281: D/dalvikvm(5457): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2799K/5379K, external 8143K/8403K, paused 48ms
03-07 23:48:55.996: D/AndroidRuntime(5457): Shutting down VM
03-07 23:48:55.996: W/dalvikvm(5457): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {izzy.n/izzy.n.main1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at izzy.n.IzzynActivity$2.onClick(IzzynActivity.java:31)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-07 23:48:56.039: E/AndroidRuntime(5457):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 23:50:31.398: D/dalvikvm(5553): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 49% free 2797K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 21ms
03-07 23:50:31.457: D/dalvikvm(5553): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 2796K/5379K, external 3471K/4335K, paused 22ms
03-07 23:50:31.660: D/dalvikvm(5553): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2798K/5379K, external 5048K/5580K, paused 25ms
03-07 23:50:31.753: D/dalvikvm(5553): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2799K/5379K, external 8143K/8403K, paused 20ms
03-07 23:50:41.910: D/AndroidRuntime(5553): Shutting down VM
03-07 23:50:41.910: W/dalvikvm(5553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {izzy.n/izzy.n.main1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at izzy.n.IzzynActivity$2.onClick(IzzynActivity.java:31)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 23:51:20.371: D/dalvikvm(5609): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 48K, 49% free 2797K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 97ms
03-07 23:51:20.503: D/dalvikvm(5609): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 2796K/5379K, external 3471K/4335K, paused 57ms
03-07 23:51:20.792: D/dalvikvm(5609): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2798K/5379K, external 5048K/5580K, paused 24ms
03-07 23:51:21.039: D/dalvikvm(5609): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2799K/5379K, external 8143K/8403K, paused 65ms
03-07 23:51:26.679: D/AndroidRuntime(5609): Shutting down VM
03-07 23:51:26.679: W/dalvikvm(5609): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {izzy.n/izzy.n.main1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at izzy.n.IzzynActivity$2.onClick(IzzynActivity.java:31)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-07 23:51:26.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5609):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 23:59:24.920: D/dalvikvm(5784): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 49% free 2797K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 54ms
03-07 23:59:25.104: D/dalvikvm(5784): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 2796K/5379K, external 3471K/4335K, paused 46ms
03-07 23:59:25.537: D/dalvikvm(5784): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2798K/5379K, external 5048K/5580K, paused 24ms
03-07 23:59:25.846: D/dalvikvm(5784): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2799K/5379K, external 8143K/8403K, paused 38ms
03-07 23:59:41.502: D/dalvikvm(5784): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 48% free 2828K/5379K, external 11785K/11958K, paused 25ms
03-07 23:59:41.740: D/dalvikvm(5784): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2829K/5379K, external 13363K/14068K, paused 25ms
03-07 23:59:41.865: D/dalvikvm(5784): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2830K/5379K, external 16457K/17091K, paused 20ms
03-07 23:59:42.607: D/AndroidRuntime(5784): Shutting down VM
03-07 23:59:42.607: W/dalvikvm(5784): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{izzy.n/izzy.n.main1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at izzy.n.main1.populateCalendarSpinner(main1.java:62)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at izzy.n.main1.onCreate(main1.java:52)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-07 23:59:42.783: E/AndroidRuntime(5784):     ... 11 more
03-07 23:59:52.850: I/Process(5784): Sending signal. PID: 5784 SIG: 9
03-08 00:11:06.982: D/dalvikvm(6029): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 46K, 49% free 2797K/5379K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 29ms
03-08 00:11:07.033: D/dalvikvm(6029): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 49% free 2796K/5379K, external 3471K/4335K, paused 20ms
03-08 00:11:07.248: D/dalvikvm(6029): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2798K/5379K, external 5048K/5580K, paused 21ms
03-08 00:11:07.350: D/dalvikvm(6029): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2799K/5379K, external 8143K/8403K, paused 19ms
03-08 00:11:10.588: D/dalvikvm(6029): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 9K, 48% free 2828K/5379K, external 11785K/11958K, paused 100ms
03-08 00:11:11.068: D/dalvikvm(6029): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 48% free 2829K/5379K, external 13363K/14068K, paused 49ms
03-08 00:11:11.365: D/dalvikvm(6029): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2830K/5379K, external 16457K/17091K, paused 47ms
03-08 00:11:11.736: D/AndroidRuntime(6029): Shutting down VM
03-08 00:11:11.736: W/dalvikvm(6029): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{izzy.n/izzy.n.main1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at izzy.n.main1.populateCalendarSpinner(main1.java:62)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at izzy.n.main1.onCreate(main1.java:52)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-08 00:11:11.752: E/AndroidRuntime(6029):     ... 11 more
03-08 00:16:11.924: I/Process(6029): Sending signal. PID: 6029 SIG: 9
03-08 00:16:14.525: D/dalvikvm(6173): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 48% free 2828K/5379K, external 11785K/11958K, paused 20ms
03-08 00:16:14.678: D/dalvikvm(6173): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 48% free 2829K/5379K, external 13363K/14068K, paused 22ms
03-08 00:16:14.779: D/dalvikvm(6173): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 48% free 2829K/5379K, external 16457K/17091K, paused 21ms
03-08 00:16:15.037: D/AndroidRuntime(6173): Shutting down VM
03-08 00:16:15.037: W/dalvikvm(6173): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{izzy.n/izzy.n.main1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at izzy.n.main1.populateCalendarSpinner(main1.java:62)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at izzy.n.main1.onCreate(main1.java:52)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     ... 11 more
```

Here is the code for Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="izzy.n"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />


     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>

    <application



        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="izzy.n.IzzynActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="izzy.n.notes"
            android:label="@string/notes"></activity>


        <activity 
            android:name="izzy.n.calculator"
            android:label="@string/calculator"></activity>


        <activity android:name="izzy.n.main1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

    </application>








</manifest>
```

and finally here is the main1.java:

```
class MyCalendar {
    public String name;
    public String id;
    public MyCalendar(String _name, String _id) {
        name = _name;
        id = _id;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class main1 extends Activity {
    /*********************************************************************
     * UI part*/
    private Spinner m_spinner_calender;
    private Button m_button_add;
    private Button m_button_add2;
    private Button m_button_getEvents;
    private TextView m_text_event;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*get calendar list and populate the view*/
        getCalendars();
        populateCalendarSpinner();
        populateAddBtn();
        populateAddBtn2();
        populateTextEvent();
        populateGetEventsBtn();
    }
    private void populateCalendarSpinner() {
        m_spinner_calender = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinner_calendar);
        ArrayAdapter l_arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, m_calendars);
        l_arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        m_spinner_calender.setAdapter(l_arrayAdapter);
        m_spinner_calender.setSelection(0);
        m_spinner_calender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> p_parent, View p_view,
                    int p_pos, long p_id) {
                m_selectedCalendarId = m_calendars[(int)p_id].id;
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });
    }
    private void populateAddBtn() {
        m_button_add = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        m_button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addEvent();
            }
        });
    }
    private void populateAddBtn2() {
        m_button_add2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_add2);
        m_button_add2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addEvent2();
            }
        });
    }
    private void populateGetEventsBtn() {
        m_button_getEvents = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_get_events);
        m_button_getEvents.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getLastThreeEvents();
            }
        });
    }
    private void populateTextEvent() {
        m_text_event = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_event);
        String l_str = "title: roman10 calendar tutorial test\n" +
            "description: This is a simple test for calendar api\n" + 
            "eventLocation: @home\n" + 
            "start time:" + getDateTimeStr(0) + "\n" + 
            "end time: " + getDateTimeStr(30) + "\n" + 
            "event status: confirmed\n" + 
            "all day: no\n" + 
            "has alarm: yes\n";
        m_text_event.setText(l_str);
    }
    /****************************************************************
     * Data part
     */
    /*retrieve a list of available calendars*/
    private MyCalendar m_calendars[];
    private String m_selectedCalendarId = "0";
    private void getCalendars() {
        String[] l_projection = new String[]{"_id", "displayName"};
        Uri l_calendars;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            l_calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        } else {
            l_calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
        }
        Cursor l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_calendars, l_projection, null, null, null);    //all calendars
        //Cursor l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_calendars, l_projection, "selected=1", null, null);   //active calendars
        if (l_managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            m_calendars = new MyCalendar[l_managedCursor.getCount()];
            String l_calName;
            String l_calId;
            int l_cnt = 0;
            int l_nameCol = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[1]);
            int l_idCol = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[0]);
            do {
                l_calName = l_managedCursor.getString(l_nameCol);
                l_calId = l_managedCursor.getString(l_idCol);
                m_calendars[l_cnt] = new MyCalendar(l_calName, l_calId);
                ++l_cnt;
            } while (l_managedCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    /*add an event to calendar*/
    private void addEvent() {
        ContentValues l_event = new ContentValues();
        l_event.put("calendar_id", m_selectedCalendarId);
        l_event.put("title", "roman10 calendar tutorial test");
        l_event.put("description", "This is a simple test for calendar api");
        l_event.put("eventLocation", "@home");
        l_event.put("dtstart", System.currentTimeMillis());
        l_event.put("dtend", System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800*1000);
        l_event.put("allDay", 0);
        //status: 0~ tentative; 1~ confirmed; 2~ canceled
        l_event.put("eventStatus", 1);
        //0~ default; 1~ confidential; 2~ private; 3~ public
        l_event.put("visibility", 0);
        //0~ opaque, no timing conflict is allowed; 1~ transparency, allow overlap of scheduling
        l_event.put("transparency", 0);
        //0~ false; 1~ true
        l_event.put("hasAlarm", 1);
        Uri l_eventUri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        } else {
            l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
        }
        Uri l_uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(l_eventUri, l_event);
        Log.v("++++++test", l_uri.toString());
    }
    /*add an event through intent, this doesn't require any permission
     * just send intent to android calendar
     * http://www.openintents.org/en/uris*/
    private void addEvent2() {
        Intent l_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        l_intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        //l_intent.putExtra("calendar_id", m_selectedCalendarId);  //this doesn't work
        l_intent.putExtra("title", "roman10 calendar tutorial test");
        l_intent.putExtra("description", "This is a simple test for calendar api");
        l_intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "@home");
        l_intent.putExtra("beginTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
        l_intent.putExtra("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800*1000);
        l_intent.putExtra("allDay", 0);
        //status: 0~ tentative; 1~ confirmed; 2~ canceled
        l_intent.putExtra("eventStatus", 1);
        //0~ default; 1~ confidential; 2~ private; 3~ public
        l_intent.putExtra("visibility", 0);
        //0~ opaque, no timing conflict is allowed; 1~ transparency, allow overlap of scheduling
        l_intent.putExtra("transparency", 0);
        //0~ false; 1~ true
        l_intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
        try {
            startActivity(l_intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, no compatible calendar is found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    /*get a list of events
     * http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151*/
    private void getLastThreeEvents() {
        Uri l_eventUri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        } else {
            l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
        }
        String[] l_projection = new String[]{"title", "dtstart", "dtend"};
        Cursor l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_eventUri, l_projection, "calendar_id=" + m_selectedCalendarId, null, "dtstart DESC, dtend DESC");
        //Cursor l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_eventUri, l_projection, null, null, null);
        if (l_managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int l_cnt = 0;
            String l_title;
            String l_begin;
            String l_end;
            StringBuilder l_displayText = new StringBuilder();
            int l_colTitle = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[0]);
            int l_colBegin = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[1]);
            int l_colEnd = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[1]);
            do {
                l_title = l_managedCursor.getString(l_colTitle);
                l_begin = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colBegin));
                l_end = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colEnd));
                l_displayText.append(l_title + "\n" + l_begin + "\n" + l_end + "\n----------------\n");
                ++l_cnt;
            } while (l_managedCursor.moveToNext() && l_cnt < 3);
            m_text_event.setText(l_displayText.toString());
        }
    }
    /************************************************
     * utility part
     */
    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy MMM dd, HH:mm:ss";
    public static String getDateTimeStr(int p_delay_min) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
        if (p_delay_min == 0) {
            return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        } else {
            Date l_time = cal.getTime();
            l_time.setMinutes(l_time.getMinutes() + p_delay_min);
            return sdf.format(l_time);
        }
    }
    public static String getDateTimeStr(String p_time_in_millis) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
        Date l_time = new Date(Long.parseLong(p_time_in_millis));
        return sdf.format(l_time);
    }
}
```

Comment: just declare Activity in manifest as .IzzynActivity without complete package name. (dot) . says this is from package declared in manifest.

Comment: share your package structure.

Comment: Can You share this part of your code izzy.n.IzzynActivity$2.onClick(IzzynActivity.java:31). More specifically the start activity command there.

Comment: Yeh it's     IzzynActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 2):

Fix this:

```
03-07 23:50:41.933: E/AndroidRuntime(5553): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {izzy.n/izzy.n.main1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

**ALSO**

Point out which line its complaining about.

Comment: This is not an answer. I have declared it as u can se

Comment: It is an answer, because that is what you need to fix. Specifically you need to post the SPECIFIC line which is causing the issue instead of making use scan your code and finding the line ourselves.

Comment: Also another thign to point is your classes are **NOT** follow the standards of Java. All class names should be uppercase. And names should be significant of what they do. Your main1 is a useless name. Next thing to do is delete it from the manifest and then add it through the GUI in the manifest.

Comment: Alright i understand that. But I can't find anything wrong so who knows if something else must be causing the error.

Comment: He's right - you did NOT declare "izzy.n.main1"  What you declared is "main1"

Comment: Its clearly with your manifest, delete the entry and re-add it though the UI and it should fix it. Also Refactor your class names to the standards with useful names.

Comment: This should fix your issue, don't forget to mark it with an answer if it solves it.

Comment: What am i supposed to delete? I dont understand your answer @JoxTraex

Comment: **READD** the entry to the manifest via the UI. That is all you should need to do to fix it. What this will do is it will use the package information/classes to populate the manifest with the proper data.

Answer (score 2):

A Object in the `populateCalendarSpinner()` method is null . Please put try catch and debug.

Your log show

`03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at izzy.n.main1.populateCalendarSpinner(main1.java:62)
03-08 00:16:15.037: E/AndroidRuntime(6173):     at izzy.n.main1.onCreate(main1.java:52)`

Activity not found is the old log. You already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

if you're sure you declared it, make sure to clean your project. Sometimes Eclipse doesn't realize your XML has changed and is acting on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name="main1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

should be

```
<activity android:name="izzy.n.main1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

Comment: Did you change main1 to izzy.n.main1 in Manifest ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name="main1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

Try with changing this to

```
<activity android:name="izzy.n.main1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Your log also says NullPointerException in `populateCalendarSpinner();` debug and fix that too.

Just do this to debug:

```
try {
    populateCalendarSpinner();
}
catch(NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: As abbas says did u debug with putting try catch in populateCalendarSpinner(); method?

Comment: No, because i'm tired and if i even try ill mess up. Tomorrow.

Comment: Weird i just edited it like this and it didnt work. public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*get calendar list and populate the view*/
        getCalendars();
        populateCalendarSpinner();
        
        try {
            populateCalendarSpinner();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        populateAddBtn();
        populateAddBtn2();
        populateTextEvent();
        populateGetEventsBtn();
    }